# Can attribute dice satisfy the prerequisites of advanced skills?

Tags: skills, star-wars-d6

Do you have to have dice in the base skill that's the prerequisite for an advanced skill, or can attribute dice satisfy the prerequisite?

Answer (score 2):

The requirement for an advanced skill is that you must have a prerequisite skill at a certain threshold. We'll use Medicine as an example, because it's in the book. That requires First Aid at 5D.

All that's required is that you get the First Aid skill up to 5D. If you're playing a race that can have a Technical attribute of 5D (e.g. Verpine), you don't need to invest any skill points in First Aid. You already have the First Aid skill at 5D, which meets the prerequisite.

(This is all based on the 2nd Edition, Revised and Expanded ruleset)